# Drupal 6 returns 403 error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am having strange problem after installing multi-site drupal environment on shared host. When executing I am getting front page and page also displays results from database without CSS and JS.

The CSS and image resources are not getting displayed which resides in /sites/all/themes/mysite/. When tried to locate CSS or JS files using URL; it returns 403 forbidden error.

Could you please help me to rectify issue?

Comment: Why do you expect something else then a 403 error?

Comment: Here the problem is page is rendered without CSS and images; just text on white background.

Comment: Asif Mulla, it looks like that you have not properly configured your installation on the server. Before trying anything else, please ensure that the default setup works. After you got it to work, you whould have no problems to modify and add own themes. Documentation how to setup Drupal is available on the Drupal homepage.

Comment: Thanks hakre. Yes problem was file permissions as some configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an apache configuration error. Either consult the apache documentation for your version, or search google (e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the theme configure page you're using and press "Save". This'll clear the theme cache. See if this works.

Comment: Can't do as even when I tried to execute admin using url www.sitename.com/admin, it returns 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on your theme folder. It should be readable for "others" ie you should have rw-r--r-- permissions on that folder and the files inside.